# How to reduce a long if condition in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**What's the best way to write following if condition in Ruby?**

```
if (    $response_code == "400" ||
        $response_code == "401" ||
        $response_code == "402" ||
        $response_code == "403" ||
        $response_code == "404" ||
        $response_code == "411" ||
        $response_code == "500" ||
        $response_code == "501" ||
        $response_code == "502" ||
        $response_code == "0")
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Ruby seems to have concise way of doing things so was wondering if I can avoid writing long stuff like this.

Comment: What aspect are you trying to reduce? Number of lines? Execution time? Total program size?

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder why you're picking up on these particular response codes? Is there some reason, for instance, that you're testing for 500, 501 and 502, but not for any of the other 5xx codes? Or are you really just wanting to test for any 4xx or 5xx (or 0) code? (BTW, I would think you'd *definitely* want to test for 418.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
ACCEPTED_CODES = %w[400 401 402 403 404 411 500 501 502 0]

def test(response_code)
  !ACCEPTED_CODES.include?(response_code)
end
```

Comment: But `$response_code` is a string, so you should probably call `to_i`.

Comment: No parameter to the test method ?

Comment: @steenslag I absolutely forgot that :)

Comment: I think `!response_code.in?(ACCEPTED_CODES)` reflects better the idea, but well, I guess it's a matter of taste... (in fact I'd use not_in?, though it's not vanila Rails)

Answer (score 4):

```
  case $response_code.to_i
  when 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 411, 500, 501, 502, 0
    return false
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if [400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 411, 500, 501, 502, 0].include?($response_code.to_i)

end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CODES = [400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 411, 500, 501, 502, 0]

return CODES.exclude? $response_code.to_i
```